# Munging data off the World Atlas of Language Structures website

Tags: python, json, csv

I have created a script to munge data off [this](http://wals.info/languoid.tab?sEcho=1&iSortingCols=1&iSortCol_0=0&sSortDir_0=asc) tab-delimited table.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from utils import sync_and_read, currentdirectory

class MiniWALS(dict):
  def __init__(self, toupdate=True):
    WALS_URL = "http://wals.info/languoid.tab?sEcho=1&iSortingCols=1"+\
            "&iSortCol_0=0&sSortDir_0=asc"
    WALS_TXT = currentdirectory()+"/data/wals/wals.txt"

    wals_tsv = sync_and_read(WALS_URL, WALS_TXT, toupdate=toupdate)
    headerline, _ , data = wals_tsv.partition('\n')

    for line in data.split('\n'):
      lang = line.split()[0]
      for key, value in zip(headerline.split('\t')[1:], line.split('\t')[1:]):
        self.setdefault(lang,{})[key] = value

    self.GENUS = defaultdict(list)
    for lang in self:
      self.GENUS[self[lang]['genus']].append(lang)

    self.LANGUAGEFAMILY = defaultdict(list)
    for lang in self:
      self.LANGUAGEFAMILY[self[lang]['family']].append(lang)

    self.RELATED_LANGS = defaultdict(list)
    for lang in self:
      self.RELATED_LANGS[lang] = self.GENUS[self[lang]['genus']] + \
                                self.LANGUAGEFAMILY[self[lang]['family']]
```

The usage of the script is to access the WALS as such (JSON-like):

```
# Accessing WALS information
>>> wals = miniwals.MiniWALS()
>>> print wals['eng']
{u'glottocode': u'stan1293', u'name': u'English', u'family': u'Indo-European', u'longitude': u'0.0', u'sample 200': u'True', u'latitude': u'52.0', u'genus': u'Germanic', u'macroarea': u'Eurasia', u'sample 100': u'True'}
```

But there are cases where it's a little verbose, e.g:

```
for key, value in zip(headerline.split('\t')[1:], line.split('\t')
```

How code this script be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few efficiency improvements I can see:

1. Don't continually do an operation on data if that data doesn't change. Take your `headerline` variable. Each time you loop through your `data`, you do `headerline.split('\t')[1:]`. This is fairly inefficient since `headerline` never changes after you assign its value and thus you only need to do the operation once instead of \$n\$ times.

   To fix this, save the result to a variable before your loop:

   ```
   relevant_headers = headerline.split()[1:]
   for line in data.split():
       . . .
   ```
2. Akin to the point above: don't do more work than you have to. You call `split` twice on `line` in your first for loop: first you split `line` and grab the language, then `split` it again to get the rest of the data. Instead of doing that, take advantage of unpacking in Python 3 or use `pop()` in Python 2:

   ```
   # Python 3   
   language, *language_data = line.split() 

   # Python 2
   language_data = line.split()
   language = language_data.pop(0)
   ```
3. You can combine your final three for loops into one loop:

   ```
   self.genus = defaultdict(list)
   self.family = defaultdict(list)
   self.related_languages = defaultdict(list)
   for language, data in self.items():
       genus = self.genus[data['genus']]
       family = self.family[data['family']]

       genus.append(language)
       family.append(language)

       self.related_languages[language] = genus + family
   ```

   Yes, we are reassigning `self.related_languages[language]` each iteration. However, this is an \$O(1)\$ operation, so it can be thought of as another basic operation. Since we now only have one for loop, only \$n\$ operations are done instead of \$3n\$. In terms of Big-O notation, the two versions perform the same; however, in terms of operation count and practical processing time, the above is better.

---

There are also a couple of style pointers I want to make:

1. Only use `ALL_CAPS` when dealing with constants. Because we cannot syntactically define constants in Python, convention is all we have to tell whether a variable is constant or not. So, unless a variable is actually supposed to be constant, do not use `ALL_CAPS`.

   To go along with this point, when dealing with multiple words in a variable name, use underscores to separate the words:

   ```
   # No
   self.LANGUAGEFAMILY

   # Yes
   self.language_family
   ```

   > **NOTE:** One exception to the rule `ALL_CAPS` rule is if you are using an acronym in a class name. So if `WALS` is an acronym, then `MiniWALS` is a slightly ambiguous, yet OK, name. Otherwise, I would suggest `MiniWals`.
2. Technically you indentation is fine. However, conventional Python uses 4 spaces to define code blocks.
3. Use `format` instead of string concatenation. This is in the style section because the performance benefits are debatable. However, using the `format` notation is much more readable and is more Pythonic:

   ```
   # Instead of this...
   WALS_TXT = currentdirectory()+"/data/wals/wals.txt"

   # ... do this.
   wals_text = '{}/data/wals/wals.txt'.format(currentdirectory())
   ```

Aside from these pointers and a few spacing issues and a not-needed `+`, your code stylistically looks fine.

---

Here is my version of your code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from utils import sync_and_read, currentdirectory

class MiniWALS(dict):
    def __init__(self, toupdate=True):
        # Unless unfeasible, I always put instance variables at the top.
        self.genus = defaultdict(list)
        self.family = defaultdict(list)
        self.related_languages = defaultdict(list)

        wals_url = 'http://wals.info/languoid.tab?sEcho=1&iSortingCols=1'\
                   '&iSortCol_0=0&sSortDir_0=asc'
        wals_text = '{}/data/wals/wals.txt'.format(currentdirectory())

        wals_tsv = sync_and_read(wals_url, wals_text, toupdate=toupdate)
        headerline, _, data = wals_tsv.partition('\n')

        relevant_headers = headerline.split()[1:]
        for line in data.split():
            # I'm assuming Python 3.
            language, *language_data = line.split()
            for key, value in zip(relevant_headers, language_data):
                self.setdefault(language,{})[key] = value

        for language, data in self.items():
            genus = self.genus[data['genus']]
            family = self.family[data['family']]

            genus.append(language)
            family.append(language)

            self.related_languages[language] = genus + family
```